# Is the conference "ICCTCEEC" a scam?

Tags: publications, conference, ieee, reputation

I submitted a paper about 20-25 days ago in this conference http://ctceec.org/ knowing about IEEE involvement here.

Today I have got an acceptance email for my paper, The astonishing thing to me is, I knew at least 1-2 month is required to review this type of conference paper.

The conference date is 8 September, 2017 which is very near. Is there anyone who can assure me that this conference is not scam?

Comment: The relatively short review period would worry me less than the exceedingly unprofessional website and the fact that the seem to accept papers on everything relating to EE or IT. I am not sure if the conference is strictly "spam", but I would bet good money that it is not worth going to.

Comment: If you have to ask, it probably is.

Comment: Have you ever cited, or even read, a paper from this conference? Do you recognize anyone on the program committee (who is not at your institution)? If you can't answer yes to both questions, you shouldn't send your paper there.

Comment: My guess would be: not a complete scam (i.e. there really will be a conference, accommodation will be booked, the talks will happen, etc), but very low scientific quality, since the range of topics covered is so implausibly vast.  The sort of conference where most participants are not really going to disseminate their research or learn about other people’s, but just so that they can list the talk on their CV and tell their department that they are travelling to international conferences.

Comment: Anyway, they are probably going to compete for the conference with the longest unpronounceable abbreviation.

Comment: What were they thinking when they designed that website?...

Comment: @MCMastery At least they refrained from making the marquee text blink ..

Comment: Also not in favour: numerous unsolicited e-mails (I have received more than 10!) with ads for this conference have been sent out from different accounts, all on an anonymously registered, now suspended domain (which happens to share the exact name servers with the official ICCTCEEC website), containing dubious shortened links.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

The website has a button that says "IEEE proof", whatever that is supposed to mean, which seems like the equivalent of a folder on your computer named "definitely not porn". Understand: they're trying suspiciously hard to use their (alleged) IEEE affiliation as a marker of legitimacy and quality.

Follow that link and enjoy that delightful prose:

> "We believe education is our motherhood and research is our motto. Our intention is to collaborate innovative brains at one place. So, here we are with "International Conference on Current Trends in Computer, Electrical, Electronics and Communication" (ICCTCEEC) platform to share, learn and discuss. We guarantee your pleasure because our city itself mean you what are we."

Let's say the intentions of the people who committed that website are not fraudulent that's still incredibly sloppy and careless not to have it proofread. Seeing this, I would doubt that anything else about that conference can be worth your time and money.

By the way, IEEE affiliation, even if legit, doesn't mean the conference is good or not spam.

The usual advice in these cases: **consult with your supervisor and colleagues.** There is typically a rather small number (~5) of conferences worthy of attending per field and any half-serious researcher knows which these are.

Comment: The IEEE proof shows that this conference has somehow been registered with IEEE, whatever that means, but for example, the deadlines given on the IEEE website for it are not the same than the ones the OP mentioned or the conference website does. So I would say, while it is not strictly a scam, it's probably not good.

Comment: The link goes to the official IEEE site, so I think the connection to IEEE is legitimate. On the other hand, [the IEEE page about conferences](https://www.ieee.org/conferences_events/index.html) says: "IEEE sponsors more than 1,800 annual conferences and events worldwide". So I wouldn't be surprised if some of those are indeed low quality.

Comment: Yeah the IEEE link makes it unlikely it's an outright scam, but I think we can all be pretty sure that the quality of the conference will be on par with their short description of the conference.. "We guarantee your pleasure because our city itself mean you what are we."

Comment: "We believe education is our motherhood and research is our motto. "  They _believe_ research is their motto.  They can't confirm that though.  Awesome.

Answer (score 11):

Registration of the conference with IEEE (i.e., [2017 International Conference on Current Trends in Computer, Electrical, Electronics and Communication (CTCEEC)](http://www.ieee.org/conferences_events/conferences/conferencedetails/index.html?Conf_ID=42587)) is a good sign that it is not an outright scam. However, I note that the conference is sponsored by the [Bangalore Section](http://ieeebangalore.org/) but I couldn't find it on their website which is troubling. Within the IEEE community this tends to imply that the section is treating the conference as a very low priority so quality control may also be quite low. Thus, while I doubt the conference is an outright scam, it likely will not stand out much more than a research colloquium for graduate students at a given university on a CV.

To elaborate a bit more on sponsorship, generally high profile conferences are sponsored by international societies (e.g., [IEEE Computational Intelligence Society](http://cis.ieee.org/) sponsors the Symposium Series on Computational Intelligence) and the conferences tend to have competitive peer review take place. Generally you will want to know what major societies in your field are and limit attendance to their conferences.

Answer (score -3):

Scam = ripping your money off: Probably not.

Scientifically worthwhile to attend: Probably neither. Just check the submission format, which is M$ Word 07 instead of LaTeX/PDF; that usually answers the question.

Touristically cool: Decide for yourself.

List of accepted papers consists of Indian authors, afai can see 100% (which is not necessarily bad, they invented zero and got Primes is in P, amongst a lot more).

Comment: -1 Whether or not there are Indian authors is kind of moot given it's a conference in India sponsored by the Bangalore Section.